# Why does this method never reach an end?

Tags: c#, events

I have a method that is like this:

```
void closeTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _closeButton.TouchUpInside -= closeTapped;

    // Other code
}
```

It is called by the `TouchUpInside` event of `_closeButton`, but as I only want this to run once, I remove the event.

Removing this event apparently causes either an exception, a fatal error, or a recursive loop, as I get a warning (by Xamarin Studio), that tells me that this method will never reach an end:

> Method never reaches an end or `return` statement

I have removed all other code in this method, and it only displays the error when the eventhandler removal is not commented. Why does this cause the method to not end?

Comment: This is probably a bug in Xamarin Studio. Maybe `_closeButton.TouchUpInside -= closeTapped` is interpreted as a recursive call to `closeTapped`.